# Getting " InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2"

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, cqrs, refresh-token, mediatr

I'm trying to implement refresh token in my api. The api is following CQRS+MediatR pattern and is using JWT for authentication.
After adding a Handler to manage refresh call and a refresh token service I am getting the following error:

> Inner Exception 1:
> InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler`2
> [UM.Business.Application.Token.Command.Update.UpdateTokenCommand,UM.Business.Application.Common.HandlerResult]
> Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: UM.Business.Application.Token.Command.Update.UpdateTokenHandler':

> Unable to resolve service for type 'UM.Infrastructure.Common.Configuration.AuthSettings'
> while attempting to activate 'UM.Business.Application.Token.Command.Update.UpdateTokenHandler'.

> Inner Exception 2:
> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'UM.Infrastructure.Common.Configuration.AuthSettings'
> while attempting to activate 'UM.Business.Application.Token.Command.Update.UpdateTokenHandler'.

My service is doing basic crud operations on the Refresh Token class.

First of all I added dependancy injection in a service module class,

```
service.AddTransient<IRefreshTokenService, RefreshTokenService>();
```

This is my controller end point,

```
        [Route("refresh")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(LoginResponse), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<string>), StatusCodes.Status412PreconditionFailed)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(string), StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ConfirmEmail), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(AccountBlocked), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Refresh([FromBody] UpdateRefreshTokenVM request, CancellationToken ct)
        {
            var refreshCommand= _mapper.Map<UpdateTokenCommand>(request);
            var authenticationResult = await _mediator.Send(refreshCommand, ct);
            if (authenticationResult == null)
                return Unauthorized();
            if (authenticationResult.IsSuccess)
                return Ok(authenticationResult.Result);
}
```

My UpdateRefreshTokenVM,

```
public class UpdateRefreshTokenVM
    {
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public Core.Domain.Models.RefreshToken RefreshToken { get; set; } }
```

And UpdateTokenCommand,

```
public class UpdateTokenCommand : CommandBase<HandlerResult>
    {
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public Core.Domain.Models.RefreshToken RefreshToken { get; set; }
    }
```

Handler getting called is this one,

```
public UpdateTokenHandler(IUserService userService, IMapper mapper, IRefreshTokenService refreshTokenService, IRoleService roleService, AuthSettings authSetting, IUserClaimsService userClaimService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
            _refreshTokenService = refreshTokenService;
            _userClaimService = userClaimService;
            _roleService = roleService;
            _authSetting = authSetting;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        public async Task<HandlerResult> Handle(UpdateTokenCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var loginResponse = new HandlerResult();
            var userIdentity = await _userService.FindByEmailAsync(request.RefreshToken.User.Email);
            string accessToken = request.AccessToken;
            var refreshToken = request.RefreshToken;
            var principal = TokenGenerator.GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(accessToken);
            var username = principal.Identity.Name; //this is mapped to the Name claim by default

            var refreshTokenFromDb =await _refreshTokenService.FindByUserId(refreshToken.User.Id);
            if (refreshTokenFromDb.RefreshTokenExpiryTime <= DateTime.Now)
            {
                return null;
            }

            if (refreshTokenFromDb == null || refreshTokenFromDb != refreshToken )
            {
                loginResponse.IsSuccess = false;
                loginResponse.ErrorMessage="Invalid client request";
                loginResponse.Result = null;
                return loginResponse;
            }

            var userClaims = await _userClaimService.GetClaims(userIdentity);
            var userRoles = await _roleService.GetUserRoles(userIdentity);
            var resultObject = TokenGenerator.GenerateJsonWebToken(userIdentity, userClaims, _authSetting, userRoles);
            //var newRefreshToken = TokenGenerator.GenerateRefreshToken();


            loginResponse.Result = resultObject;
            loginResponse.ErrorMessage = null;
            loginResponse.IsSuccess = true;

            //user.RefreshToken = newRefreshToken;
            //userContext.SaveChanges();

            // now save the token variable in db
            await _refreshTokenService.UpdateAsync(resultObject.RefreshToken);

            return loginResponse;
        }
    }
```

Following is the token generator used in the handler,

```
        internal static LoginResponse GenerateJsonWebToken(UM.Core.Domain.Models.User userInfo,IList<System.Security.Claims.Claim> userClaims, AuthSettings authSetting, IList<string> roleNames)
        {
            userClaims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, userInfo.Email));
            userClaims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, userInfo.Id));
            userClaims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userInfo.NormalizedUserName));
            foreach(string name in roleNames)
            {
                userClaims.Add(new System.Security.Claims.Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, name));
            }
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authSetting.Key));

            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor()
            {
                Issuer = authSetting.Issuer,
                Audience = authSetting.Audience,
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(userClaims),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(authSetting.ExpirationTimeInMin),
                SigningCredentials = credentials
            };

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

            // Now generate refresh token
            var refreshToken = new RefreshToken
            {
                User = userInfo,
                //UserId = int.Parse(userInfo.Id),
                RefreshTokenString = GenerateRefreshToken(),
                RefreshTokenExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(14)  // will change this later
            };

            var authenticationResponse = new LoginResponse
            {
                AccessToken = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token),
                RefreshToken = refreshToken,
                IsValid = true
            };
            return authenticationResponse;

        }

        public static string GenerateRefreshToken()
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[32];
            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
            {
                rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);
            }
        }

        public static ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipalFromExpiredToken(string token)
        {
            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateAudience = false, //you might want to validate the audience and issuer depending on your use case
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345")),
                ValidateLifetime = false //here we are saying that we don't care about the token's expiration date
            };
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            SecurityToken securityToken;
            var principal = tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, tokenValidationParameters, out securityToken);
            var jwtSecurityToken = securityToken as JwtSecurityToken;
            if (jwtSecurityToken == null || !jwtSecurityToken.Header.Alg.Equals(SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                throw new SecurityTokenException("Invalid token");
            return principal;
        }
```

Auth settings(which I didn't touch for this implementation)

```
 public class AuthSettings
    {
        public string Key { get; set; }
        public string Issuer { get; set; }
        public string Audience { get; set; }
        public int ExpirationTimeInMin { get; set; }
    }
```

And my login Response class,

```
public class LoginResponse
    {
        public string AccessToken { get; set; }
        public RefreshToken RefreshToken { get; set; }
        public bool IsValid { get; set; }
        public bool VerificationRequired { get; set; }
        public bool TwoFactorRequired { get; set; }

        public LoginResponse()
        {
            RefreshToken = new RefreshToken();
        }
    }
```

Comment: this `AuthSettings` should be registered as a singleton (init with some settings) ***but*** you should better use `IOptions<AuthSettings>`. You need to configure the options for it (maybe binding it with some section under the `IConfiguration`). You can learn more about Configuration & Options in ASP.NET Core. This is an easy to fix issue. It's terrible that no one even has given a comment or answer before this comment of mine. Oh SO :(

Comment: Why do you create your own JWT tokens?

Comment: @KingKing, Thankyou so much, that worked.
I wish you had written this as an answer, so I could upvote it.

Comment: @ToreNestenius, Initially there were some other developers who worked on it, much senior than me, they did it like this and took all other api decisions.

Comment: @ToreNestenius, what should've been a better way?

Comment: Using a more trusted way to created tokens, like using IdentityServer or using some other  third party trusted OpenID Connect token provider like Auth0, Ping, AzureAD.... Creating your own is hard and many times they will have various security issues, like Apple when they modified openid connect https://www.republicworld.com/technology-news/other-tech-news/apple-pays-100000-to-delhi-based-hacker-for-sign-in-with-apple-sec.html